# Replacing columns in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a 5x167 column array, with 167 rows 
example:

```
1 2 3 4 5, 
1 2 3 4 5, 
1 2 3 4 5, 
1 2 3 4 5, 
1 2 3 4 5, 
etc
```

I have another 1x167 column array of numbers, let's say 0's. I'd like to take this 1x167 column array and replace the middle (3rd) column with this array while deleting the 4th column so I get an array like this.

```
1 2 0 5,
1 2 0 5,
1 2 0 5,
1 2 0 5,
etc
```

How would I replace a whole column like this? I keep getting an array full of 0's

Comment: Show us what you have tried so that we can help. (include your code in the question)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take some random data:

```
M = rand( 167, 5 ); % Your 5 column matrix
N = rand( 167, 1 ); % Your new column
```

You can delete the 4th column like so:

```
M(:,4) = [];        % Remove 4th column
```

Then replace the 3rd column

```
M(:,3) = N;         % Replace 3rd column of M with N
```

Alternatively, you can construct the matrix in one line

```
M = [ M(:,1:2), N, M(:,5) ]; % Construct new matrix by concatenating columns
```

Comment: @Daniel no problem, please consider marking this question as "accepted" if it answered your question.